# Umbraco 10 Examine search with wildcards

Tags: c#, umbraco, examine

I'd like to change the following code to include a leading and trailing wildcard.
At present it it searching on the index 'bodyBlockListSearch' which I created to index all block list content.  It works but I can see it omits content that would be included if it had wildcards.  Any help appreciated.

```
_examineManager.TryGetIndex("ExternalIndex", out IIndex? index);
var results = index.Searcher.CreateQuery()
               .Field("bodyBlockListSearch", searchText)
               .Execute();
```